# Title displayed 2 times in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, ecmascript-6, fullcalendar

[image]

My title is displayed 2 times on fullcalendar, I don't know why, the script looks fine and all are working. I'm leaving my script here.

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

      var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        locale: 'es',
        plugins: ['interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timegrid', 'list'],
        header: {
          center: 'title',
          right: 'prev,next today,dayGridMonth,listMonth'
        },
        defaultDate: new Date(),
        navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
        selectable: true,
        selectMirror: true,
        select: function() {
          $('#newevent').modal({
            keyboard: false
          });
          calendar.unselect()
        },
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: [

        ]
      });

      calendar.render();
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Right before `center: 'title',`, try to add `left: '',`

Answer (score 0):

Am curious about the version used, still your code looks like old version and you got answer in the comment. But I like to share about the latest version.
[Link](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/headerToolbar)

Upgrade to latest v5

1. header -> headerToolbar (just rename)
2. The properties can be start/center/end or left/center/right